# Docker windows 10 pro volume directories not writable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other Project:
[image]

I am facing directory permission errors on all of my docker projects. And this is one of them in Laravel. I have run 'chown' for directory permissions on /var/www and shared my 'c' drive where host project files are. Is it related to windows local/domain user permissions ?

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY . /var/www
COPY ./vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www

ENV TERM xterm

COPY ./ssl/server.crt /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
COPY ./ssl/server.key /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_mysql mysqli && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) tokenizer bcmath ctype
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN service apache2 restart

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer


EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Answer (score 1):

Check which user is used to run your application. Since you mount your volume via command-line, the folder will be mounted as the `docker`-user. The `docker`-user will probably have other permissions than the user that runs the app e.g. the àpp`-user cannot write to the mounted folder.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i check that ?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: I added the dockerfile